# It is possible to write the value of an xml attribute (attrs.xml) with java code?

Tags: android, android-attributes, attrs.xml

Having this attrs.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="customColorPrimary" format="color" value="#111111"/>
</resources>
```

It is possible to write with java code a new value for that color?

Can't find how to do it in the official documentation...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: All `resources` you use in your code are compiled as contents of `R` class. Every single `resource` (including `string`, `dimen`, `layout`, `style`, `attr` and other) is compiled as some variation of `public static`**`final`**`int` values. That's why you can't modify it during runtime.